# How much faster are arrays than accessing Google Sheets cells within Google Scripts?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How much faster is accessing and manipulating an array in google scripts vs accessing and manipulating data from a google sheet?

Here's the application:

I am working on a program to create a schedule for employees. My strategy is to create a list of available employees for each day, randomize the list, and then insert a random employee into each open slot one by one based on specific parameters. Then repeat for each day of the week until the schedule is filled.

Sometimes the parameters aren't met given the randomized list, and I need to restart the loop. On average I'll run ~1100 iterations of the loop until the schedule is filled. If the GoogleScript runs >6 min then it results in a timeout of the function and it's stopped automatically.

My function is a mix of accessing data from GoogleSheets and accessing data directly from arrays within the function. In general, would there be a noticeable difference to re-write my function such that all the data is directly stored and manipulated within an array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The impact magnitude will depend on how much reading and writing you are doing. If a lot of incremental data transfer is currently used, then changing your approach can yield massive benefit.

Calls to the Spreadsheet API generally take 0.01 seconds or more to complete. Calls that import / export data, or call sub-functions, will take longer (e.g. `getDataRange`, `getValue(s)`, `setValue(s)`).  Apps Script is smart enough to optimize some successive calls, but if you are alternating reads and writes, then nothing on Google's end can help you.
You can view this timing data on the `View -> Execution Transcript` menu.

My suggestion is to move any existing cell-based validation formulas into script functions that operate on a passed employee name, an object mapping between employees and the shifts they have already "worked", and the proposed shift to work. Then you'd be able to use 1 call to import the employee - day availability list, and for each day, for each shift, validate that a randomly chosen available employee can work it, given their previous shifts in the scheduling period. Lastly, you'd write your object back to the sheet(s).

---

Timing Script (which gets internally optimized by google due to successive reads)

```
function writeRand_(rows, cols)
{
  var datasheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid).getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  datasheet.getDataRange().clearContent();
  var rand = [];
  for(var row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
  {
    var data = [];
    for(var col = 0; col < cols; ++col)
      data.push(Math.random());
    rand.push(data);
  }
  datasheet.getRange(1, 1, rand.length, rand[0].length).setValues(rand);
  return datasheet;
}

function readAndTime()
{
  var rows = 50, cols = 8;
  var datasheet = writeRand_(rows, cols);
  // sum one-by-one
  var sum1 = 0;
  var startRangeSum = new Date().getTime();
  for(var row = 1; row <= rows; ++row)
    for(var col = 1; col <= cols; ++col)
      sum1 += datasheet.getRange(row, col).getValue()-0;
  var endRangeSum = new Date().getTime();
  // Read all, then sum.
  var sum2 = 0;
  var startArraySum = new Date().getTime();
  var inputs = datasheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var row = 0; row < inputs.length; ++row)
    for(var col = 0; col < inputs[0].length; ++col)
      sum2 += inputs[row][col]-0;
  var endArraySum = new Date().getTime();
  Logger.log("Value count: " + rows * cols);
  Logger.log("Range sum: " + (endRangeSum - startRangeSum)/1000 + " sec. " + sum1);
  Logger.log("Array sum: " + (endArraySum - startArraySum)/1000 + " sec. " + sum2);
}
```

The above gives me ~.8s for range and .2s for array - and that .2s is essentially all due to the time it takes to call `getDataRange()` to make `inputs`

Answer (score 0):

tehhowch says properly =)
I do it like that.

```
/* The first couple of nested loops use only reading methods as well as based on this 
    they pick up cells whose value must be changed in the array for next loop
*/

for (var rowIndex = editedCell.getRow(); rowIndex <= wageGrid.getLastRow(); rowIndex++) {
  if (weBreak) break;

  for (var collIndex = (rowIndex == editedCell.getRow()) ? (editedCell.getColumn() + 1) : wageGrid.getColumn(); collIndex <= wageGrid.getLastColumn(); collIndex++) {

    var cell = aSheet.getRange(rowIndex, collIndex);
    var cellFontColor = cell.getFontColor();
    var cellYearAndMonth = aSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 1).getValue();
    var cellDay = aSheet.getRange(1, collIndex).getValue();

    if (cellFontColor == "#ff0000") {

      weBreak = true;
      break;
    }
    if (aSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 1).getValue().getMonth() == cellYearAndMonth.getMonth()) {

      cellsToSetValue.push(cell);
    }
  }
}

//the next loop has an array of cell and perform only "set" methods

for (var cellIndex = 0; cellIndex <= cellsToSetValue.length; cellIndex++) {

  cellsToSetValue[cellIndex].setValue(evt.value);
}
```

thus there are only two delays when the API optimizes work of "get" and "set" methods and between them everything happens bearable fast )