# Import from CSV is very slow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My script (see below) is very slow while i'm importing a csv table into Google Sheets. Anyone have an idea where the problem is?

I tried it already on different accounts

Greetings

```
function import_konto_kst_statistik_budget() {
  var fSource = DriveApp.getFolderById('1B2t86GVMoB4yilJ5ieWuGpxFYzsVm8bs'); // reports_folder_id = id of folder where csv reports are saved
  var fi = fSource.getFilesByName('konto_kst_statistik_budget.csv'); // latest report file
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('90_konto_kst_statistik_budget'); // Select Sheet Konto
  sheet.activate()  // aktiviert das Sheet Konto
  sheet.clear()  // löscht alle Inhalte auf Sheet Konto

  if ( fi.hasNext() ) { // proceed if "konto.csv" file exists in the reports folder
    var file = fi.next();
    var csv = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
    csv = csv.replace(/'/g, '"');
    var csvData = CSVToArray(csv); // see below for CSVToArray function

    // loop through csv data array and insert (append) as rows into 'NEWDATA' sheet
    for ( var i=0, lenCsv=csvData.length; i<lenCsv; i++ ) {
      sheet.getRange(i + 1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It does not really matter the speed of the transfer, unless it is for active calculations.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49020131/how-much-faster-are-arrays-than-accessing-google-sheets-cells-within-google-scri/49020786#49020786

Answer (score 2):

Your script is slow due to this loop:

```
for ( var i=0, lenCsv=csvData.length; i<lenCsv; i++ ) {
      sheet.getRange(i + 1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
  }
```

change it to:

```
sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
```

**Reason:** 
Write operations using setValues have huge overhead and take longer, so try to [write your data in one go where ever possible.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations)

**Edit:**
If the reason you input one row at a time is that you have a variable length of the column in your CSV data. I would suggest modifying your `CSVtoArray()` function to return an array with uniform column length

Comment: What is ``i`` at ``csvData[i].length`` of changed one? If ``CSVtoArray()`` has uniform column length, is it ``0`` instead of?

Comment: it should be csvData[0].length, just modified it

Comment: Thanks for your advice
i get an error with your code (sorry is in german)

"Falsche Bereichsbreite, war 4, sollte jedoch 1 sein. (Zeile 159, Datei "Code")Schließen" 

Translated with google Translator

Wrong area width was 4, but should be 1. (Line 159, file "Code") Close

Comment: I figured as much, the array length are not equal. If you look at the spreadsheet sheet atleast the first row would be written into.

Comment: Could you post your csvtoarray() function and an example csv file to verify the same.